# multiple words search in a sentence using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a column containing sentences in a standard format. I am trying to retrieve the rows where sentence contains  particular key words.

data is like this

```
***Damage, Location, Near Location***

Corrosion, Bonnet, Left Head light

Corrosion, Bonnet, Right Head light

Corrosion, Left Door, Near Handle

Scratch, Right Door, Near Handle

Dent, Right Door, Near Handle

Dent, Bonnet, Left Head light

list1=[corrosion,Bonnet]
```

I am trying to pass words as list (list1) and i only need the rows which have both words. I tried contains but working only for one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `contains` here:

```
list1 = ['Corrosion', 'Bonnet']
regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(list1) + r')\b'
df[df['data'].str.contains(regex, regex=True)]
```

By the way, the regex pattern we are using here to search is an *alternation*, which says to match any of the search terms:

```
\b(?:Corrosion|Bonnet)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume, you have a dataframe as `df`

```
df = df[(df['Damage'] == list[0]) & (df['Location'] == list[1])]
```